# Excel custom sort list works in Excel but not when file is transferred to SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, sharepoint

I created a custom sort list of fiscal weeks that I use for my reports in Excel. For many reports I also use them as a Slicer. I have come across the issue where this **custom sort list works perfectly in Excel, but when I place the file in SharePoint, Excel no longer applies the custom list and it just sorts alphabetically**. It not only doesn't show the pivot tables in the right order, but it even rearranges the Slicer to show the fiscal weeks in alphabetical order. Not sure if this is an Excel setting or a SharePoint setting that may need to be modified, thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "I place the file in SharePoint"? Do you upload and open in Excel online? Or still open in desktop version of Excel?

Comment: Thank you Máté and yes, what I meant by placing the Excel file in SharePoint is uploading it to my team's SharePoint which is where I'm facing the problem. Once in SharePoint, the sorting no longer works correctly when viewing it in Excel online, or even when you open the file for editing through the Desktop App (in Excel).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Open the Excel file in the SharePoint and Click on the Filter and Sort- Custom Sort-Select the Column- Use the Cell Values in the Sort On-In the order, select either Sort Ascending or Sort Descending-OK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).